# mySQL index reset to zero

Tags: mysql

I need to rebuild the index of a mySQL table, so that to start from 0 again, as some fields deleted. I did CREATE a new index, DROP the old, make the new one as primary key, but it is not starting from 0.
Also through OPTIMIZE TABLE & REPAIR TABLE go OK, the table & DB works always fine, but the index is not reset to 0. Is is possible automatically somehow, or with mySQL just manually?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean auto-increment Primary key ?

Comment: can you post your table create statement so we have some context around what you're working with and trying to adjust?

Comment: Almost for sure you do not need to do it.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `DB` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: For the moment quite not. I am just afraid to let it go bigger and take space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using an AUTO-INCREMENT int as your index, a simple statement should correct this:

```
    ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: 3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
13
14
15
16
18
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
76
86

Comment: I got finally, in addition to your support "For InnoDB you cannot set the auto_increment value lower or equal to the highest current index". Thank you!